Customizing useBlockProps
I'm making a custom block to insert video. I've added some styling options with the BorderControl component.
Options selected with the component are applied by default to the block in the editor without applying useBlockProps:
return (
    <></>
);

See video capture:
https://youtu.be/g5s8eBBIeOM
That is, I haven't needed to use …useBlockProps. Gutenberg seems to apply those attributes automatically to the root element.
If I try to apply useBlockProps to an element of my choice, I get a duplicate of the attributes. One on the element it is applied on by default and one on the chosen element. I am applying useBlockProps like this.
return (
    <div {...useBlockProps()}></div>
);

See video capture:
https://youtu.be/nin8bYEZRn4
Default attributes are always rendered and I can't customize their location. Is it possible to remove the default rendering of BlockProps and use my own customization?
block.json:
export default {
  name: `sage/video`,
  title: `Video`,
  category: `fb`,
  icon: CustomIcon,
  attributes: {
    libraryId: {
      type: 'string',
      default: '265348',
    },
    videoId: {
      type: 'string',
      default: '',
    },
    thumbnailUrl: {
      type: 'string',
      default: '',
    },
    align: {
      type: 'string',
      default: 'none',
    },
    autoplay: {
      type: 'boolean',
      default: false,
    },
    loop: {
      type: 'boolean',
      default: false,
    },
    muted: {
      type: 'boolean',
      default: false,
    },
    controls: {
      type: 'boolean',
      default: true,
    },
    playsInline: {
      type: 'boolean',
      default: true,
    },
    style: {
      type: 'object',
      default: {
        border: {
          color: '',
          radius: '0px',
          style: 'solid',
          width: '1px',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  supports: {
    align: ['wide', 'full'],
    spacing: {
      margin: false,
      padding: false,
    },
  },
  edit: Edit,
  save: () => null,
};

Edit.jsx:
import {
  TextControl,
  PanelBody,
  ToggleControl,
  Button,
  ToolbarGroup,
  ToolbarButton,
  __experimentalBorderControl as BorderControl,
  __experimentalUnitControl as UnitControl,
} from '@wordpress/components';
import {
  InspectorControls,
  BlockControls,
  MediaUpload,
  MediaUploadCheck,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useEffect, useState } from '@wordpress/element';
import VideoPlayer from '../../components/video/VideoPlayer';
import { Eye, Edit3 } from 'react-feather';

const EditVideo = ({ attributes, setAttributes }) => {
  const {
    videoId,
    thumbnailUrl,
    autoplay,
    loop,
    muted,
    controls,
    playsInline,
    libraryId,
    style,
  } = attributes;

  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(true);

  const removeImage = () => {
    setAttributes({ thumbnailUrl: '' });
  };

  const colors = [
    { name: 'Black', color: '#000000' },
    { name: 'White', color: '#FFFFFF' },
    // Añade más colores según sea necesario
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <BlockControls>
        <ToolbarGroup>
          <ToolbarButton
            icon={
              isEditing ? (
                <Eye className="feather-icon" />
              ) : (
                <Edit3 className="feather-icon" />
              )
            }
            label={
              isEditing
                ? __('Switch to Preview', 'sage')
                : __('Switch to Edit', 'sage')
            }
            onClick={() => setIsEditing(!isEditing)}
          />
        </ToolbarGroup>
      </BlockControls>
      <InspectorControls>
        <PanelBody title={__('Video Settings', 'sage')}>
          <ToggleControl
            label={__('Autoplay', 'sage')}
            checked={autoplay}
            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ autoplay: value })}
          />
          <ToggleControl
            label={__('Loop', 'sage')}
            checked={loop}
            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ loop: value })}
          />
          <ToggleControl
            label={__('Muted', 'sage')}
            checked={muted}
            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ muted: value })}
          />
          <ToggleControl
            label={__('Playback Controls', 'sage')}
            checked={controls}
            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ controls: value })}
          />
          <ToggleControl
            label={__('Play Inline', 'sage')}
            checked={playsInline}
            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ playsInline: value })}
          />
        </PanelBody>
        <PanelBody title={__('Style Settings', 'sage')}>
          <PanelBody title={__('Style Settings', 'sage')}>
            <BorderControl
              colors={colors}
              label={__('Border', 'sage')}
              value={{
                color: style.border.color,
                style: style.border.style,
                width: style.border.width,
                radius: style.border.radius,
              }}
              withSlider={true}
              width="100px"
              onChange={(newBorder) => {
                setAttributes({
                  style: {
                    ...style,
                    border: {
                      color: newBorder.color,
                      style: newBorder.style,
                      width: newBorder.width,
                      radius: newBorder.radius,
                    },
                  },
                });
              }}
            />
            <UnitControl
              label={__('Border Radius', 'sage')}
              value={style.border.radius}
              onChange={(newRadius) => {
                setAttributes({
                  style: {
                    ...style,
                    border: {
                      ...style.border,
                      radius: newRadius,
                    },
                  },
                });
              }}
            />
          </PanelBody>
        </PanelBody>
      </InspectorControls>
      {isEditing ? (
        <>
          <TextControl
            label={__('Video ID', 'sage')}
            value={videoId}
            onChange={(id) => setAttributes({ videoId: id })}
            placeholder={__('Enter Bunny.net video ID...', 'sage')}
            className="m-4"
          />
          <TextControl
            label={__('Library ID', 'sage')}
            value={libraryId}
            onChange={(id) => setAttributes({ libraryId: id })}
            placeholder={__('Leave blank to get default library', 'sage')}
            className="m-4"
          />
          <MediaUploadCheck>
            <MediaUpload
              onSelect={(media) => setAttributes({ thumbnailUrl: media.url })}
              allowedTypes={['image']}
              render={({ open }) => (
                <div>
                  {thumbnailUrl ? (
                    <div>
                      <img
                        src={thumbnailUrl}
                        alt={__('Thumbnail', 'sage')}
                        className="block w-60 mx-4 mt-4"
                      />
                      <Button
                        onClick={open}
                        variant="secondary"
                        className="m-4"
                      >
                        {__('Change Thumbnail', 'sage')}
                      </Button>
                      <Button onClick={removeImage} variant="destructive">
                        {__('Remove Thumbnail', 'sage')}
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={open} className="m-4">
                      {__('Select Thumbnail', 'sage')}
                    </Button>
                  )}
                </div>
              )}
            />
          </MediaUploadCheck>
        </>
      ) : (
        videoId && (
          <VideoPlayer
            videoId={videoId}
            thumbnailUrl={thumbnailUrl}
            autoplay={autoplay}
            loop={loop}
            muted={muted}
            controls={controls}
            playsInline={playsInline}
          />
        )
      )}
    </>
  );
};


Hard to say with the current code. Please include your block.json and your implementation of BorderControl in your Edit.jsx.

Thank you for your attention. I've included both edit.jsx and block.json in the question.

The problem occurs because the block uses the style property internally to set the styles of the block with useBlockProps(). So your own implementation sets the same set of styles as you would do with a core block.
The easiest solution is to enable the - for now - expiremental border controls. This will give you the same border controls as the core blocks have, so you don't have to create them in your Edit.jsx.
export default {
  name: 'sage/video',
  title: 'Video',
  category: 'fb',
  icon: CustomIcon,
  attributes: {
    libraryId: {
      type: 'string',
      default: '265348',
    },
    videoId: {
      type: 'string',
      default: '',
    },
    thumbnailUrl: {
      type: 'string',
      default: '',
    },
    align: {
      type: 'string',
      default: 'none',
    },
    autoplay: {
      type: 'boolean',
      default: false,
    },
    loop: {
      type: 'boolean',
      default: false,
    },
    muted: {
      type: 'boolean',
      default: false,
    },
    controls: {
      type: 'boolean',
      default: true,
    },
    playsInline: {
      type: 'boolean',
      default: true,
    }
  },
  supports: {
    align: ['wide', 'full'],
    spacing: {
      margin: false,
      padding: false,
    },
    __experimentalBorder: {
      color: true,
      radius: true,
      style: true,
      width: true,
      __experimentalDefaultControls: {
        color: true,
        radius: true,
        style: true,
        width: true,
      },
    }
  },
  edit: Edit,
  save: () => null
};

import {
  TextControl,
  PanelBody,
  ToggleControl,
  Button,
  ToolbarGroup,
  ToolbarButton,
} from '@wordpress/components';

import {
  useBlockProps,
  InspectorControls,
  BlockControls,
  MediaUpload,
  MediaUploadCheck,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useEffect, useState } from '@wordpress/element';
import VideoPlayer from '../../components/video/VideoPlayer';
import { Eye, Edit3 } from 'react-feather';

const EditVideo = ({ attributes, setAttributes }) => {
  const {
    videoId,
    thumbnailUrl,
    autoplay,
    loop,
    muted,
    controls,
    playsInline,
    libraryId,
    style,
  } = attributes;

  const blockProps = useBlockProps();
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(true);

  const removeImage = () => {
    setAttributes({ thumbnailUrl: '' });
  };

  const colors = [
    { name: 'Black', color: '#000000' },
    { name: 'White', color: '#FFFFFF' },
    // Añade más colores según sea necesario
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <BlockControls>
        <ToolbarGroup>
          <ToolbarButton
            icon={
              isEditing ? (
                <Eye className="feather-icon" />
              ) : (
                <Edit3 className="feather-icon" />
              )
            }
            label={
              isEditing
                ? __('Switch to Preview', 'sage')
                : __('Switch to Edit', 'sage')
            }
            onClick={() => setIsEditing(!isEditing)}
          />
        </ToolbarGroup>
      </BlockControls>

      <InspectorControls>
        <PanelBody title={__('Video Settings', 'sage')}>
          <ToggleControl
            label={__('Autoplay', 'sage')}
            checked={autoplay}
            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ autoplay: value })}
          />
          <ToggleControl
            label={__('Loop', 'sage')}
            checked={loop}
            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ loop: value })}
          />
          <ToggleControl
            label={__('Muted', 'sage')}
            checked={muted}
            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ muted: value })}
          />
          <ToggleControl
            label={__('Playback Controls', 'sage')}
            checked={controls}
            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ controls: value })}
          />
          <ToggleControl
            label={__('Play Inline', 'sage')}
            checked={playsInline}
            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ playsInline: value })}
          />
        </PanelBody>
      </InspectorControls>

      {isEditing ? (
        <>
          <TextControl
            label={__('Video ID', 'sage')}
            value={videoId}
            onChange={(id) => setAttributes({ videoId: id })}
            placeholder={__('Enter Bunny.net video ID...', 'sage')}
            className="m-4"
          />

          <TextControl
            label={__('Library ID', 'sage')}
            value={libraryId}
            onChange={(id) => setAttributes({ libraryId: id })}
            placeholder={__('Leave blank to get default library', 'sage')}
            className="m-4"
          />

          <MediaUploadCheck>
            <MediaUpload
              onSelect={(media) => setAttributes({ thumbnailUrl: media.url })}
              allowedTypes={['image']}
              render={({ open }) => (
                <div>
                  {thumbnailUrl ? (
                    <div>
                      <img
                        src={thumbnailUrl}
                        alt={__('Thumbnail', 'sage')}
                        className="block w-60 mx-4 mt-4"
                      />
                      <Button
                        onClick={open}
                        variant="secondary"
                        className="m-4"
                      >
                        {__('Change Thumbnail', 'sage')}
                      </Button>
                      <Button onClick={removeImage} variant="destructive">
                        {__('Remove Thumbnail', 'sage')}
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={open} className="m-4">
                      {__('Select Thumbnail', 'sage')}
                    </Button>
                  )}
                </div>
              )}
            />
          </MediaUploadCheck>
        </>
      ) : (
        videoId && (
          <div {...blockProps}>
            <VideoPlayer
              videoId={videoId}
              thumbnailUrl={thumbnailUrl}
              autoplay={autoplay}
              loop={loop}
              muted={muted}
              controls={controls}
              playsInline={playsInline}
            />
          </div>
        )
      )}
    </>
  );
};


Thanks for your reply. I have removed the custom style attributes and added support for __experimentalBorder and __experimentalDefaultControls as you have indicated. This has improved the block because it now has the standard controls. But the problem is the same: without adding blockProps the border is rendered on the block. If I add blockProps, I get the duplicate border.

Is there something in the VideoPlayer component that also uses the style property? When you inspect the blocks can you see where the borders are being applied to?

The video component does not use the style property. Also, I am experiencing the same problem in other simpler blocks, it seems like a general behavior, not specific to this block. The style is applied to the block root element with the class block-editor-block-list__block.

Hmm, it would help if there is a way to reproduce the issue that you have, as this behavior doesn't happen on my end.
